# bootstrap dialog with ajax - how to open using jquery or javascript?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap ajax modal that works fine when I click the link below, however I want to only open it from jquery or javascript. Here is the link:

Ajax Modal

I have tried using the following - however it does not work unless I have clicked the link prior to executing the jquery.

$("#ajax").modal();

Here is the html code for modal

```
<div class="modal-header"><!-- modal header -->
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Complete Sale process</h4>
</div><!-- /modal header -->

<!-- modal body -->
<div class="modal-body">

    These changes were made:



    Pay - on accoun t / Cash / Eftpos / etc

</div>
<!-- /modal body -->

<div class="modal-footer"><!-- modal footer -->
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close and make changes</button> 
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Confirm and complete</button>
</div><!-- /modal footer -->
```

Do I have to initialise it first ? Please help.

Comment: Please post your html code for the modal.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: I have updated the post to include the html. Thanks.

Comment: So you want your modal to open with a click but before opening, you want to decide whether to show or not??